# Hangfire Automatic retries - how to manually configure the time between retries

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have a requirement to manually configure the time between retries. I was not able to find the way for it.

But I found a code from https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/AutomaticRetryAttribute.cs

which schedule job after maximum number of retries are finished.

```
public static readonly int DefaultRetryAttempts = 10;
```

I have changed above property `DefaultRetryAttemts` to `3` instead of `10` then also it is taking 10 retries for a single job

> 'Retry attempt 7 of 10: Error while importing data'

My requirement is to have 5 retry attempts and provide 20 minutes delay after each retry.

Answer (score 18):

[This feature](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/931/) has been merged to version 1.7 beta. For whoever wants to get the feature early, copy the [new AutomaticRetryAttribute code](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/dev/src/Hangfire.Core/AutomaticRetryAttribute.cs) to your project, rename it to AutomaticRetryExtAttribute and apply both attributes to your job.

[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)] is applied to prevent it from rescheduling jobs upon failure. It is important because we want AutomaticRetryExt to handle the rescheduling instead.

```
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
[AutomaticRetryExt(Attempts = 30, DelaysInSeconds=new int[] { 300 })]
public static async Task Download(string fileName)
{
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to make it global, you can do it so by adding a global filter on your startup configuration:

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 5, DelaysInSeconds = new int[] { 300 } });
```

You can even specify each retry timeout by having:

```
DelaysInSeconds = new int[] { 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been merged in Hangfire trunk and should be available in version 1.7. See [the pull request](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/931/)

You may just look at the pull request and retrieve the code of the `AutomaticRetryAttribute` to build your own custom attribute.